# GmailApi get messages on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gmail-api

I am trying to get all messages from gmail Using GmailApi But when i run the code this error shows up

"**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yousefelsayed.myemail/com.yousefelsayed.myemail.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null**"

And it tell me that the error is from this Line

```
ListThreadsResponse listResponse = mService.users().threads().list("me").execute();
```

What is the problem

MyCode :

```
mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), SCOPES)
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());

    HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();

    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    mService = new com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, mCredential)
            .setApplicationName(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .build();
try {
            ListThreadsResponse listResponse = mService.users().threads().list("me").execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Edit :

Full error:

```
05-28 09:15:39.836 22385-22385/com.yousefelsayed.myemail E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.yousefelsayed.myemail, PID: 22385
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yousefelsayed.myemail/com.yousefelsayed.myemail.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2583)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
    at android.accounts.Account.<init>(Account.java:48)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzg.getToken(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:267)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:292)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:880)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:542)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:475)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:592)
    at com.yousefelsayed.myemail.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6301)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2530)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

05-28 09:15:39.983 805-1769/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)

Comment: I suggest that you [edit] your question and post the entire stack trace you are getting.

Comment: Not sure if this will fix the issue, but you're using deprecated classes and methods. Should use [Class NetHttpTransport](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/http/javanet/NetHttpTransport.html) instead of [AndroidHttp](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/extensions/android/http/AndroidHttp.html) in order to build the service. The call itself seems to be all right.

Comment: I used this class but same error

Comment: I'd suggest you to follow [this quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java).